# Kernel basis of a transformation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to find the kernel basis of the transformation matrix:

\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & -1 & 1 & -1\\
  1 &  0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}

I have reduced the matrix to :

\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  0 &  1 & 1 & 1\\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}

I see we have one free variable (x4). How do I go on from here?

Answer (score 1):

Express the remaining variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$ in terms of your free veraiable $x_4$, using the fact that the reduced matrix must annihilate $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$.

Comment: From the RREF I get the system: x1 = 0; x4 = -x2 -x3; x3 = 0. So i guess the final result would than be: x4 = - x2?

Comment: Since you are solving for $x_1,x_2,x_3$ I woudlwrite the second equation as $x_2=-x_4$ instead. All in all $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=x_4(0,-1,0,1)$. By the way, you have just a row-echelon form, not a reduced row-echelon form, but that is OK, you don't need the latter.